# Decoding 1 byte with a 1 byte key

Tags: encryption, hex, byte, decode

I have developed an app that receives information from a server, automatically reads the packet and saves it as a floating point in a database.

Example: 
Data received(00 00 D0 41) -> Reverse order(41 D0 00 00) ->  Convert to floating point (26.0)

Lately that information has slightly changed, instead of sending 4 bytes the server now sends 5.

Example:
0A 0C 0C C0 0F

I figured out that the first byte is some sort of key, and when this key is 06, the data is not encrypted.

Example:
06 00 00 D0 41

The only keys I've seen so far are 00 06 08 and 0A.

Samples meaning the same:
    06 00 00 D0 41 (original, key 06)
    08 32 32 12 B4 (coded with key 08)
    00 EF EF 1B BF (coded with key 00)
    0A 0C 0C C0 0F (coded with key 0A)

For what it seems, it only encodes byte by byte, I reached this conclusion because on several packets, I know what the original byte is and the encrypted byte stays the same.

Example: 00 (key 06) = 32 (key 08) = EF (key 00) = 0C (key 0A) in every packet.

I have found some logic in numbers with a difference of 4,

Key 0A

```
00=>0C
04=>1C
08=>6C
0C=>7C
10=>CB
14=>DB
18=>2C
1C=>3C
20=>8B
24=>9B
28=>EB
2C=>FB
30=>4D
34=>5D
38=>AD
3C=>BD
```

My question is, what is the best way to find out the encryption algorithm?

- Should I brute force multiple operations (xor, rotate, and,...) and see if they are a match?
- Are there algorithms that have this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer the two related questions sequentially.

- Yes, I would brute force the algorithm using the usual suspects. Don't forget addition (modulo 256).
- This is not an algorithm that I know of, it doesn't seem to be encoding or encryption, more a question of obfuscation.

Modern encryption algorithms do not deal with known, single byte keys and produce data indistinguishable from random. It's not encoding either, there are at least bytes in there that seem to be outside the ones expected for character encoding or e.g. BCD encoding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is the answer I was looking for, could you give me some tips on how you would brute force it? Also, do you know any program that can actually help me?

Comment: I usually don't do analysis. There must be some sites or applications that would be able to do this in an automated fashion, but I would not know how. That said, this one I could probably figure out by pen/paper or something similar (writing things down in binary instead of hex). It would take time though.

Comment: I am actually using that method (pen/paper), but the fact that I don't have that much data does not help. I will try and find a freelancer to help me out, thank you.